# How To Create Frame With Two Columns of Labels using Python and Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I would like to create a table of n rows and 2 columns with a header. I am aware of TkinterTreeCtrl but do not want to use it. I read up on the grid manager and wrote some sample code but it does not at all do what I want it.

Firstly, it shows two rows instead of two columns.
Secondly, when I comment out the line `self.sensorTable.pack()` I expect to see only the quit button because the two labels were slaves of the columns which in turn were slaves of the sensorTable.

```
from Tkinter import *


class Window:

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()

        self.sensorTable = Frame(master=self.root)
        self.sensorNameColumn = LabelFrame(self.sensorTable, text="Name", padx=5, pady=5).grid(row = 0, column = 0)
        self.sensorValueColumn = LabelFrame(self.sensorTable, text="Value", padx=5, pady=5).grid(row = 0, column = 1)

        w = Label(master=self.sensorNameColumn, text="Hello")
        w.pack()

        w2 = Label(master=self.sensorValueColumn, text="World")
        w2.pack()

        #self.sensorTable.pack() # commenting this out should mean that the two entries are not seen on the window but they are for some reason

        quit_button = Button(self.root, text="Quit", command=self.quit)
        quit_button.pack(side=BOTTOM)

    def begin(self):
        mainloop()

    def quit(self):
        self.root.quit()     # stops mainloop
        self.root.destroy()


if __name__=="__main__":
    Window().begin()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`grid`, `pack` methods return `None`. You need to separate widget creation statement and `grid`-call statement.

```
self.sensorTable = Frame(master=self.root)
self.sensorNameColumn = LabelFrame(self.sensorTable, text="Name", padx=5, pady=5)
self.sensorNameColumn.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
self.sensorValueColumn = LabelFrame(self.sensorTable, text="Value", padx=5, pady=5)
self.sensorValueColumn.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
```

Otherwise, `self.sensorNameColumn`, `self.sensorValueColumn` become `None`; causing `w`, `w2` to be children of `root`; That's why those labels are shown regardless of `self.sensorTable.pack()`.